# Get spring-data-mongodb to honor getter/setter without backing field?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a general-purpose POJO:

```
public class Thing {
    private String name;
    private String etc;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // other getters and setters
}
```

I'm using Spring 4.3.9 and Spring-data-mongodb 1.10.4. I want to store instances of this POJO in Mongodb, but I have some constraints:

1. I can't add Spring annotations to the base class (but I can subclass `Thing` and annotate that).
2. I want to use the `name` field as the Mongodb unique ID (mainly to avoid creating a separate unique index for it).
3. I want to (redundantly) store the `name` field as an actual field named "name", so that other consumers of the collection don't have to know that "name" is stored in the `_id`.

I started out trying this:

```
public class SpringThing extends Thing {
    @Id
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        super.setName(name);
    }
}
```

This causes spring to use the value of `name` for `_id`, but of course it doesn't store a field named "name" in Mongodb. [The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling) says that spring will use a "property or field" named "id" or annotated with `@Id`. So I tried defining a redundant getter/setter which accesses the name field:

```
public class SpringThing extends Thing {
    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return super.getName();
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        super.setName(id);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, spring ignores `getId` and `setId` here, and stores the object with an autogenerated ID. I also tried creating redundant getters/setters annotated with `@Field("name")`, but spring seems to ignore any getter/setter pair without an actual field.

Adding an actual ID field and storing a copy of the name there does work:

```
public class SpringThing extends Thing {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Override
    public void setName(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        super.setName(id);
    }
}
```

But it requires defining a pointless field named "id".

Is there a more reasonable way to get what I want? Is what I'm trying to do reasonable to begin with?

Comment: Have you tried adding [`@AccessType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/AccessType.html) to your Spring-specific class? Alternatively, you could store the class you can't change as nested document, if that pattern works for you.

Comment: @mp911de I wasn't aware of the AccessType annotation. I tried adding it to the getId/setId attempt, and it has the desired effect--spring uses getId/setId for the unique ID. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Care to add an answer if you have found a solution?  Would be very useful to see a full example.

Comment: @woemler Added an answer. Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to a hint by @mp911de, I ended up creating a subclass of `Thing` that looks like this:

```
@TypeAlias("thing")
@Document(collection = "things")
public class SpringThing extends Thing {

    @Id
    @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getId() {
        return super.getName();
    }

    public void setId(String taskName) {
        super.setName(taskName);
    }
}
```

- The `@TypeAlias` annotation overrides the name which spring would use for the type, to cover up the fact that I've created a subclass just to add annotations.
- `@Id` says that this is the getter for `_id`.
- `@AccessType` says to access this field through the getter and setter rather than by directly accessing the field. This is what I needed; without it, spring looks for a private member variable named something like `id`.
- `@JsonIgnore` is the Jackson (JSON library that we're using) annotation to prevent including the `id` field when serializing these objects to JSON.